# Discrepance between an array response from graphQL and same array printed with a console log

Tags: javascript, arrays, graphql

I have a very strange behaviour and I need your help.
I retrieve a list of content from a GraphQl API that i attach you:

```
client.query({query: PAGES_LIST}).then(res => console.log(res.data.pages)
```

The problem is that the response from the network is that:

```
[
    {
        "id": "ddf",
        "title": "DDF",
        "type": "HOME",
        "draft": false,
        "newtonId": "64edfc8f3508bb20a9dbef19",
        "creationDate": "2023-08-29 14:11:27",
        "updatedDate": "2023-08-29 14:18:24",
        "__typename": "Page"
    },
    {
        "id": "home",
        "title": "Aujourd'hui",
        "type": "HOME",
        "draft": false,
        "newtonId": "649f004bdd86676fc0b4fb7e",
        "creationDate": "2023-06-30 16:18:19",
        "updatedDate": "2023-06-30 16:18:19",
        "__typename": "Page"
    },
    {
        "id": "home",
        "title": "Aujourd'hui",
        "type": "HOME",
        "draft": true,
        "newtonId": "64e4694ede8dac1164feabd4",
        "creationDate": "2023-08-22 07:52:46",
        "updatedDate": "2023-10-31 10:35:26",
        "__typename": "Page"
    },
    {
        "id": "newpage",
        "title": "New Page",
        "type": "HOME",
        "draft": true,
        "newtonId": "6540db14d9696820b319a6af",
        "creationDate": "2023-10-31 10:46:44",
        "updatedDate": "2023-10-31 10:46:44",
        "__typename": "Page"
    }
]
```

And the console.log from the client side is that. As you could see the item with the same id "home" is the same now:

```
[
    {
        "__typename": "Page",
        "id": "ddf",
        "title": "DDF",
        "type": "HOME",
        "draft": false,
        "newtonId": "64edfc8f3508bb20a9dbef19",
        "creationDate": "2023-08-29 14:11:27",
        "updatedDate": "2023-08-29 14:18:24"
    },
    {
        "__typename": "Page",
        "id": "home",
        "title": "Aujourd'hui",
        "type": "HOME",
        "draft": false,
        "newtonId": "649f004bdd86676fc0b4fb7e",
        "creationDate": "2023-06-30 16:18:19",
        "updatedDate": "2023-06-30 16:18:19"
    },
    {
        "__typename": "Page",
        "id": "home",
        "title": "Aujourd'hui",
        "type": "HOME",
        "draft": false,
        "newtonId": "649f004bdd86676fc0b4fb7e",
        "creationDate": "2023-06-30 16:18:19",
        "updatedDate": "2023-06-30 16:18:19"
    },
    {
        "__typename": "Page",
        "id": "newpage",
        "title": "New Page",
        "type": "HOME",
        "draft": true,
        "newtonId": "6540db14d9696820b319a6af",
        "creationDate": "2023-10-31 10:46:44",
        "updatedDate": "2023-10-31 10:46:44"
    }
]
```

How is it possibile and could I solve it ?

I excpect to see the same array that the newtowrk provides me.

Comment: Probably [this `console` behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284663/console-log-shows-the-changed-value-of-a-variable-before-the-value-actually-ch). Something modified the array *after* you logged it.

Comment: I use the consol only for debugging. I'm trying to cycle it and merge the same into a unique object with the 2 newtonId and I found 2 identical newtonId

Comment: use `console.log(JSON.stringify(yourarray))` instead and see if the issue persists

Comment: I solved the problem. Apollo client normalized the id field so prevent to duplicate it and merge into the first the first information. here i found the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938885/apollo-client-replaces-an-array-of-objects-with-the-same-id-and-different-values

Comment: Yes, this answer solved the problem